# Problem in contract verification through EtherScan API

Tags: solidity, etherscan, contract-verification

Contract source verification through these [APIs](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/apis#contracts) is putting it 'pending in queue' and not getting confirmed.

[This interface](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/sourcecode-demo.html) is also behaving same.

[image]

I tried it with rinkeby and kovan.

[Here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/verifyContract2) it works fine.

Comment: It's always "pending in queue" for a certain amount of time (usually a few seconds). Maybe they're just experiencing some delays.

Comment: Yes, usually it is pending for few seconds but its been 4-5 hours and still pending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned here: https://www.reddit.com/r/etherscan/comments/bcbojh/problem_in_contract_verification_through_api/ekwxfnr?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

It was under some maintenance.